# How to read number of words in a line in C txt file

Tags: c, file, scanf

Hi I have an array of pixels which I have written in a text file using fprintf. I am trying to get the number of rows and columns but I noticed that fscanf does not take into account the newline so when I use it, I can only get the total amount of numbers. Is there another way to get the number of rows and columns?

```
100 255 244 200
999  11  23  41
234   0  23 111
```

Comment: check [getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) this may be helpful and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917718/how-to-read-data-from-file-into-two-dimension-array-in-c/64918412#64918412)

Comment: for number of rows- [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), for number of columns, *possibly* [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)

Comment: Can you name a maximum of possible columns?

Comment: Two of your lines end in a blank, the last one does not. Is that a fleixbility of the input or can you guarantee that all end in exactly one blank and only the last line ends without?

Comment: This could be a one liner, with strict input format. Please provide a data structure in which you intend to store the read values. Filling it might take another line....

Answer (score 0):

Number of rows is equal to number of `\n` plus one (If last byte is not `\n`). Number of columns is equal to number of single space plus one (Donot count extra space for columns).  I read the total contents of the file and stored it into an character array, then I counted number of `\n` and spaces, to find number of rows and columns.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char arr[1024]; // Increase size according to the file size.
    ssize_t count;
    int isLineReach = 0;
    int row = 0, cols =0;
    fd = open("RowCol.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd >= 0)
    {
        count = read(fd, arr, 1024); // reading from file and writing to array.
        if (count == -1)
        {
            printf("Error %d\n", errno);
            exit(0);
        }
        arr[count] = '\0';
    }
    
   else
    {
       printf("Error opening a file %d\n", errno);
       exit(0);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<count-1; i++) // count--> Total number of characters including `\n` and `' '` space
    {
        if(arr[i] == '\n') // Checking for number of lines
        {
            row++;
            isLineReach = 1;
        }

        else if(arr[i] == ' ' && isLineReach != 1 && arr[i+1] !=' ') // Checking for number of spaces in a line
        {
            cols++;
        }
        
    }

    printf("The number of rows are %d\n",(row+1));
    printf("The number of columns are %d\n",(cols+1));

    return 0;
    close(fd);
}
```

RowCol.txt contents :

```
100 255 244 200
999  11  23  41
234   0  23 111
123 234 123 0
112 230 43 12
123 234 43 10
133 321 23 12
100 123 67 89
102 34 45 67
104 123 43 54
120 165 23 23
```

The output is :

```
The number of rows are 11
The number of columns are 4
```

Comment: why use non standard functions when the standard library is perfectly capable of achieving this?

Comment: Also what if the file is bigger than 1024 bytes? Also, this counts the number of spaces to identify the number of columns, what if the first row is `234   0  23 111`

Comment: `arr[i + 1]` *may* read out of bounds for the condition `i < count`, change the condition to `i < count - 1`

Comment: *Number of rows is equal to number of \n plus one.* why add one if the last byte is a newline?

Comment: @chqrlie Add one, if last byte is not `\n`.  If last byte is `\n`, no need to add 1.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula: OK. For the number of columns, beware of initial and trailing spaces: your method fails on those, counting space `1` space newline as 3 columns.

Comment: Furthermore reading the file with `read` is inappropriate, use the standard stream functions.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes it will fail for that case. But OP has mentioned the format of data in the question. I think code works for the format OP mentioned.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula: in the OP's example, the numbers are right aligned. All 3 rows start with a 3 digit number, so the file happens to not have any initial spaces, but if a row would start with a lesser number, you would have a problem. Better to use defensive programming and handle all cases.

Answer (score 0):

For rows, [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) will suffice to read line by line

```c
size_t rows = 0;
char buffer[256] = {0};
FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if (!f)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file\n");
    return 1;
}
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f) != NULL)
{
    if (strchr(buffer, '\n') != NULL)
    {
        // Increment row counter if a newline is present in the string
        rows++;
    }
    else if (feof(f))
    {
        // Increment even if there's no newline but EOF has been reached
        rows++;
    }
}
fclose(f);
printf("rows: %d\n", rows);
return 0;
```

`fgets` will read in at most `sizeof(buffer) - 1` characters or upto the first newline encountered, whichever comes first.

This means some reads where the line is greater than the size of the buffer (in this case 256), the full line will not be read. So we need to check if a newline actually exists in the string with [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) before incrementing.

For columns, assuming all lines have the same number of columns, you can simply count the number of spaces (non-continuous) from a `buffer` containing the full line

```c
size_t columns = 0;
char buffer[256] = {0};
FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if (!f)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file\n");
    return 1;
}
// Read the first line in full, keep trying until a newline is encountered
while (strchr(buffer, '\n') == NULL && fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f) != NULL)
{
    // Keep track of whether or not actual column data has been encountered
    bool data_encountered = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(buffer) - 1; i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] != ' ')
        {
            // NOTE: This assumes any non space character is valid column data
            data_encountered = true;
        }
        else if (data_encountered)
        {
            // Encountered space, if column data had been encountered prior - increment count
            columns++;
            // Reset data_encountered
            data_encountered = false;
        }
    }
}
// Increment columns one last time if line ended with a non space character
size_t bufferlen = strlen(buffer);
if (buffer[bufferlen - 1] == '\n')
{
    // Buffer ended in a newline, check the character just before it
    // Increment column count if the last character (excluding newline is a valid column data)
    columns += (buffer[bufferlen - 2] != ' ');
}
else
{
    // Increment column count if the last character (excluding newline is a valid column data)
    columns += (buffer[bufferlen - 1] != ' ');
}
fclose(f);
printf("columns: %d\n", columns);
return 0;
```

The loop keeps calling `fgets` until a newline character is present in the buffer, i.e a line has been read. Inside the loop, for each buffer, the number of spaces (non-contiuous) are added to the counter, representing columns.

**If you know beforehand** the *upper bound of the number of columns*, and even the *upper bound of the number of characters per line* - you *won't need* all these safeguards. But this will be robust in situations where you **cannot make a guess**.

Now, how do you combine them? I'd advice keeping them in separate functions, one for counting rows, and another for counting columns. Don't be worried about performance, the compiler will take care of that if it sees these 2 functions being called near each other.

But if you insist on doing all of this in the same function, here's an efficient implementation-

```c
int columns = 0, rows = 0;
char buffer[256] = { 0 };
FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if (!f)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file\n");
    return 1;
}
// Extract the first line and count the columns
while (strchr(buffer, '\n') == NULL && fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f) != NULL)
{
    // Keep track of whether or not actual column data has been encountered
    bool data_encountered = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(buffer) - 1; i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] != ' ')
        {
            // NOTE: This assumes any non space character is valid column data
            data_encountered = true;
        }
        else if (data_encountered)
        {
            // Encountered space, if column data had been encountered prior - increment count
            columns++;
            // Reset data_encountered
            data_encountered = false;
        }
    }
}
// Increment columns one last time if line ended with a non space character
size_t bufferlen = strlen(buffer);
if (buffer[bufferlen - 1] == '\n')
{
    // Buffer ended in a newline, check the character just before it
    // Increment column count if the last character (excluding newline is a valid column data)
    columns += (buffer[bufferlen - 2] != ' ');
}
else
{
    // Increment column count if the last character (excluding newline is a valid column data)
    columns += (buffer[bufferlen - 1] != ' ');
}
// Increment rows by one, since one line has been read already
rows++;
// Reset all cells in the buffer to 0
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
// Count the rest of the lines
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f) != NULL)
{
    if (strchr(buffer, '\n'))
    {
        rows++;
    }
    else if (feof(f))
    {
        rows++;
    }
}
fclose(f);
printf("rows: %d\n", rows);
printf("columns: %d\n", columns);
```

**NOTE**: Headers to be included for the code-

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Comment: A file composed of exactly 2 bytes: a space and `1`, will be analysed as `rows: 0` and `cols: 2` which seems incorrect on both counts.

Comment: @chqrlie well, I alluded to such edge cases and wanted to leave some fun to the OP, but sure I'll edit the full solution in to handle all the cases