# Creating a singly linked list from a .txt file and reversing odd numbers of each line in C

Tags: c

I have a project about linked lists but I'm having a hard time doing it. The teacher wants me to read a .txt file and create singly linked list from it. After that, I need to reverse odd numbers of every line. Then print it. Here is the code which I used for printing the linked list. But I need help to reverse the odd numbers of each line.

This is the code which I used to print the list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct list {
    char *string;
    struct list *next;
};

typedef struct list LIST;

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char line[10];
    LIST *current, *head;

    head = current = NULL;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
        LIST *node = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
        node->string = strdup(line);
        node->next =NULL;

        if(head == NULL){
            current = head = node;
        } else {
            current = current->next = node;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    
    for(current = head; current ; current=current->next){
        printf("%s", current->string);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the content of the .txt file:

```
10
9,6,11,7,12,18,19,14,15,13
13,14,9,12,15,3,18,20,1,2
4,11,8,17,12,15,20,10,3,16
19,4,11,1,13,17,12,16,20,18
1,6,20,11,13,9,7,16,10,2
12,4,11,16,3,20,9,19,17,15
20,3,10,12,18,2,5,14,15,16
18,19,15,2,6,9,1,3,17,4
7,6,20,1,11,4,3,5,8,16
1,2,16,13,17,10,12,9,4,15
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse"? Thanks.

Comment: `char line[10];` this should have more size, since you have more bytes than 10

Comment: `current = current->next = node;` what do you want to achieve with this, are you sure you are getting all the contents of .txt file?

Comment: I mean first line should be like: 13,6,15,19,12,18,7,14,11,9. And yeah, i am able to print all txt file right now.

Comment: Another thing is your `fgets` does not read the full line as per your file, so better use [getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) if it is allowed as it is posix, and see the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917718/how-to-read-data-from-file-into-two-dimension-array-in-c/64918412#64918412) for example

Comment: @IrAM - `getline()` is a POSIX standard function unless you are sure this is being written in a POSIX environment, it won't work.

Comment: right @ryyker , updated comment

Comment: IMHO, having multiple assignments in one operator does not save anything at run-time and makes code harder to read.

Comment: @zzz777 it was just for printing the .txt file as singly linked list.

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz: I meant that code like that is better write in two lines:  current = head = node -> head = node; current = node;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hope this code will do the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct line {
    struct num *first;
    struct line *next;
} LineNode;

typedef struct num {
    int num;
    int order;
    struct num *next;
} NumNode;

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    int counter = 0;
    NumNode *curr_num, *even_ptr, *odd_ptr, *odd_head, *even_head;
    LineNode *curr_line, *line_head;

    curr_num = even_head = odd_head = even_ptr = odd_ptr = NULL;
    line_head = curr_line = NULL;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    while(ch != EOF){
        if (ch >= 48 && ch <= 57)
        {
            int n = 0;
            while (ch != EOF && ch != '\n' && ch >= 48 && ch <= 57)
            {
                int x = ch - 48;
                n = n * 10 + x;
                ch = fgetc(fp);
            }
            NumNode *node = malloc(sizeof(NumNode));
            node->num = n;
            node->order = counter;
            node->next =NULL;

            if (n % 2 == 0){
                if(even_head == NULL){
                    even_head = even_ptr = node;
                } else {
                    even_ptr = even_ptr->next = node;
                }
            }else{
                if(odd_head == NULL){
                    odd_head = node;
                } else {
                    node->next = odd_head;
                    odd_head = node;
                }
            }

            counter++;
        }
        

        if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)
        {
            NumNode *num_node, *head;
            num_node  = head = NULL;
            even_ptr = even_head;
            odd_ptr = odd_head;
            counter = 0;

            if (even_head != NULL && even_head->order == counter){
                head = num_node = even_ptr;
                even_ptr = even_ptr->next;
            } else {
                head = num_node = odd_ptr;
                odd_ptr = odd_ptr->next;
            }
            
            counter++;

            while (even_ptr != NULL)
            {
                if (even_ptr->order == counter) {
                    num_node = num_node->next = even_ptr;
                    even_ptr = even_ptr->next;
                } 
                else if (odd_ptr != NULL) {
                    num_node = num_node->next = odd_ptr;
                    odd_ptr = odd_ptr->next;
                }

                counter++;
            }

            while (odd_ptr != NULL)
            {
                num_node = num_node->next = odd_ptr;
                odd_ptr = odd_ptr->next;
            }
            
            
            LineNode *node = malloc(sizeof(LineNode));
            node->next =NULL;
            node->first = head;
            if (line_head == NULL)
                line_head = curr_line = node;
            else
                curr_line = curr_line->next = node;

            odd_head = even_head = NULL;
            counter = 0;
        }

        ch = fgetc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    for(curr_line = line_head; curr_line != NULL ; curr_line=curr_line->next) {
        for(curr_num = curr_line->first; curr_num != NULL ; curr_num=curr_num->next) {
            printf("%d", curr_num->num);
            if (curr_num->next != NULL)
                printf(",");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OMG Thanks a lot dude. I don't know how to thank you :)

Comment: @ryyker, Bob Jarvis and also others also thank you all for your helps...

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz just upvote the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> *"But I need help to reverse the odd numbers of each line."*

There are several other parts that need to be considered before this step can be developed.

Following are suggestions for a functions approach implementation using your problem description.  A few items are simply suggestions to simplify the existing code.  And a few other steps, are not mentioned as necessary, but should be considered:

- Since you are not mandated to use `char *string;` in your problem description, choose to use a reasonable `string` length variable that does not require an additional layer of dynamic allocation, such as `char string[260];` (or even smaller to fit your input file.)  This will greatly simplify the code.
- Because the input file is sized with lines ~30 char long, declare the variable `line` to be at least large enough to contain one line, eg `80` would allow larger values, and still allow enough space, but since memory is cheap, go with the same size as is used in the `string` member of your linked list.
- Move the work of populating each new node to a ***function***.  It also will greatly simplify the program, and provide greater readability.  Eg: `void insert(LIST **head_ref, char *str);`
- Always test the return of `fopen()` before attempting to use the file descriptor.
- To manipulate the contents of each odd row (eg 1, 3, 5, 7, 9), as numbers, the contents of each line read in from a file as a string, needs to first be converted to a collection of numbers.  This suggests an additional member be added to the `struct`.  For example `int num[10]`.
- The previous observation implicitly suggests the need of an additional ***function*** to parse and convert each comma delimited string into discrete integer values.  Perhaps with the prototype:  `void parseIntArray(LIST **list);`
- The next and final task also suggests an additional ***function*** to reverse the contents of selected array member integer arrays. This one might use a prototype such as: `void reverse_odd(LIST **list, size_t size);`
- Finally, because each node of LIST created required dynamically allocated memory, once finished using LIST, the memory must be given back to the OS to prevent memory leaks.  An additional function to do this could be prototyped: `void freeList(LIST **head);`

Following are the `main()` function and preceding support declarations etc.  It is intended here to illustrate the above suggested steps, and the benefits of breaking down a bigger problem into smaller problems, then implementing each smaller solution to support the whole. Benefits include for example readability and maintainability and potential re-use of code-base,  (Note the similarity of argument lists in each supporting function.):

```
#define MAX_STRLEN 260  //use mnemonic values to avoid magic numbers in code

struct list {
    char string[MAX_STRLEN];
    int arr[10];
    struct list *next;
};
typedef struct list LIST;

//Prototypes of 'smaller' solutions
void insert(LIST **head_ref, char *str);
void parseIntArray(LIST **list);
void reverse_odd(LIST **list, size_t size);
void freeList(LIST **head);

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAX_STRLEN];
    LIST *current, *head;
    char *convPtr = NULL;

    head = current = NULL;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        //consume 1st line
        if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp));//10
        {
            sizeArray = strtol(line, &convPtr, 10);
            if(errno != ERANGE)
            {
                while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
                {
                    //(see implementations of each below)
                    //create new node, insert num string
                    insert(&current, line);
                    //convert new->string to integers, place in new->array
                    parseIntArray(&current);
                    //reverse 'odd' contents of each array
                    reverse_odd(&current, sizeArray);
                }
            }else{//handle error and leave}
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }else{//handle error and leave}
    //At this point in code, entire file is captured into nodes of list.  
    //use list as needed
    //When finished using list, memory must  be freed to prevent memory leaks
    head = current;
    freeList(&head);

    return 0;
}
```

The remaining code segments are the function implementations used above:

```
void freeList(LIST **head)
{
   LIST *tmp;

   while (*head != NULL)
    {
       tmp = (*head);
       (*head) = (*head)->next;
       free(tmp);
    }
}

//create new node, insert num string
void insert(LIST **head_ref, char *str)  
{  
    int *arr = malloc(numNodes * sizeof(*arr));
    //allocate node
    LIST* new = calloc(1, sizeof(*new)); 

    //put in the data
    strcpy(new->string, str); 

    //Make next of new node as head
    new->next = (*head_ref);  

    //Move the head to point to the new node
    (*head_ref) = new;  
}  
//convert new->string to integers, place in list->array
void parseIntArray(LIST **list)
{
    char *tok = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    char *sArray = strdup((*list)->string);
    tok = strtok(sArray, ",\n ");
    while(tok)
    {
        errno = 0;
        tmp = atoi(tok);
        if(errno == ERANGE)
        {
            printf("Error converting string to number\nExiting.");
            return;
        }
        (*list)->arr[i] = tmp;
        i++;
        tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n "); 
    }
}
//reverse 'odd' contents of list->array              
void reverse_odd(LIST **list, size_t size)
{
    int *ptr = &((*list)->arr[0]);
    int *tmp = malloc(size * sizeof(*tmp));
    memset(tmp, -1, size*sizeof(*tmp));
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(ptr[i]%2 != 0) 
                tmp[size-1-i] = ptr[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(tmp[i] < 0)
        {
            while((*ptr)%2 != 0 ) ptr++;
            tmp[i] = *ptr;
            ptr++;
        }
    }
    memcpy((*list)->arr, tmp, size*sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestions but using array structs are forbidden to use, he wants us only to work on singly linked list. Also teacher mentioned that solution is based on stack and queue combinations. Also i changed `char line[]` to 120. I can print all .txt file, just i got stuck on reversing the lines.

Comment: also i saw `void append(LIST **head_ref, char *new_data);` function but i couldn't understand how to implement it. So, can you give more details or share a pseudocode with me?

Comment: From the description of `append`, I'd **guess** that you should A) walk the list until you find a node with `next == NULL`, and then B) create a new node, C) set the new node's `string` to point to `new_data`, and D) change the `next` pointer in the node found in step (A) to point to the new node created in (B). That's just a guess - the other option would be to create a new node and position it at the *head* of the list, which is faster. It's your code, make your own choice. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica - Thanks.  Yes, that would make more sense here. Thanks.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis - Reinstate Monica, ryyker.  Thank you, i will try your suggestions, i would inform you later about this :)

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz - I agree with BobJs suggestion in his comment that rather than appending to end of list, it would be better to insert new node at beginning of list, that said, do you know how to do that?

Comment: Actually no, i was thinking to search and learn how to use that. But i would get help from you gladly :D. I am just stupid to understand how to make that numbers pretend like inputs. Everywhere i looked got input from user and constructed the linked list

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz -  This is it in a nutshell, without comments:  `{ LIST* new = calloc(1, sizeof(*new)); 
    strcpy(new->string, str);   
    new->next = (*head_ref);  
    (*head_ref) = new; }`  )`  This creates a new node, then sets head node to its location.  This particular implementation also copies the string data that would have been read from the file (in a loop) before calling.  At the end of the loop, there would be 10 nodes, each containing a populated string from the file.  The conversion would ha

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz - ...The conversion from string to 10 numbers would also be done from a call to another function from within this one, but did not want to clutter up this illustration.  And also, I am not using an array of struct.  I use only a single instance of struct for each new node.  I cannot believe that your instructor would inhibit the use of an array as a member i.e. to represent the string read from a file, or to represent an array of 10 integers.

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz - Sorry, this is the function prototype _including_ the part I left off two comments ago:  `void insert(LIST **head_ref, char *str) { LIST* new = calloc(1, sizeof(*new));      strcpy(new->string, str);        new->next = (*head_ref);       (*head_ref) = new; } )`

Comment: Yeah, i believe too he cannot prevent that too much. Instructor said: "Write a C program that reads a line from data.txt and creates a singly linked list queue from it. This program changes that queue order by reversing the order of the odd integers while leaving the even integers in place.
Run this program for each line of the data.txt file and print out the results.
The first line of the data.txt file contains the sample count.

Use Singly Linked List, not Array! Solution is based on stack and queue combination." Another problem is understanding the project well...

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz - Is this statement a verbatim quote from the instructor's instructions:  _"This program changes that queue order by reversing the order of the odd integers while leaving the even integers in place."_ ?

Comment: @ryyker yes, i copied and pasted his quotes.

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz - I can see the singly linked list (that is what I have been describing from the beginning.) but although I can see how reversing the order of integers contained in say the member of node 1 as  `int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` to  `{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}`, I do not see how changing the order of nodes within the collection of 10 nodes makes any sense.

Comment: @ ryyker Oh, no. I explained it how should it be at before comments. Maybe you have missed it. The order should be like : 9,2,7,4,5,6,3,8,1,10.

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz - I get it.  So, does this manipulation need to occur in each node, or only in the odd ones.

Comment: @ryyker Yeah, for nodes which contains odd integers. :). So i am open to new suggestions. Hehe